# Issue with WP Cron does not appear to be working correctly - Wordpress

Tags: cron, wordpress

The wordpress site has been showing the message "Problem with WP Cron does not appear to be working correctly". We have tried a lot of things, but nothing.
This problem appeared from nowhere.

We have disabled possible cron jobs that would interfere with wordpress, we have tried erasing 'cron' from the database... but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You may try using WP CLI with the command `wp cron test --debug` to test your WordPress cron. You may learn more about the command here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/test/

If you don't want to use CLI, you may check your wp-config.php manually. If there is `DISABLE_WP_CRON` or `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON`, you can either remove it from your wp-config.php, or add a cron job through `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/wordpress/wp-cron.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, i have tried installing WP CLI to see the state of cron, it tells me it's ok, that it's working fine, but obviously it's not. I've tried with 'wp cron event run --due-now' and it keeps telling me it's working fine... i don't know what to do now